# Animating a UISlider

Tags: ios, uislider

I'm animating a UIView, UIText, UILabel and UIImage element in my app to transition into position on button click which works perfectly. However the code I am using doesn't work on a UISlider and I can't figure out way. Can anyone help me out. My code is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations: ^{
    if (!viewExpanded) {   //x y width height
        viewExpanded = YES; //going down
        _blueMove.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 150); //slide down panel
        _titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 247, 44); // player title
        _timeElapsed.frame = CGRectMake(40, 95, 34, 21); //time counter
        _duration.frame = CGRectMake(230, 95, 35, 21); //duration
        _playerBg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 84, 320, 45); //player bg colour box

    }else{  //going up
        viewExpanded = NO;
        _blueMove.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 0);//slide down panel
        _titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(30, -40, 274, 44);// player title
        _timeElapsed.frame = CGRectMake(40, -20, 34, 21); //time counter
        _duration.frame = CGRectMake(230, -20, 35, 21); //duration
        //_currentTimeSlider = CGRectMake(40, 0, 175, 34); //time slider
        _playerBg.frame = CGRectMake(0, -45, 320, 45); //player bg colour box


    }
```

You can see I've commented out an example of what I'm using in the else statement to animate my UISlider but this throws up an error.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `_currentTimeSlider.frame = ...`?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted has the slider commented out

```
  //_currentTimeSlider = CGRectMake(40, 0, 175, 34); //time slider
```

And it's also missing .frame